# Wrong output or read from stdin, C++

Tags: c++

My program:

```
int main() {  
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;

        printf("%i, %i\n", a, b);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Why my output is:

```
551124992, 551129087
2147483647, 551129087
2147483647, 551129087
...
```

if input is:

```
81
551124992 551129087
2205057024 2205061119
4204900352 4204904447
2341777408 2341781503
```

I expect to see a different response:

```
551124992, 551129087
2205057024, 2205061119
4204900352, 4204904447
...
```

But if my input is

```
2
12 15 
2 3
```

I have a right output:

```
12, 15 
2, 3
```

I don't understand, what's wrong. Here is a demo: https://ideone.com/izmRCn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `long long` in your demo, but the format specifier for it is invalid. It should be `%lli`, not simply `%i`:

```
// This is copied from your demo:
while (t--) {
    long long a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    // This is modified
    printf("%lli, %lli\n", a, b);
    //       ^^    ^^
}
```

[Demo (forked from your code).](https://ideone.com/NPzTWB)

Answer (score 4):

These numbers are too large to fit in an `int` (assuming 32-bit `int`s, as on Windows):

```
81
551124992 551129087
2205057024 -> 2205061119 <-
4204900352 -> 4204904447 <-
2341777408 -> 2341781503 <-
```

The maximum value that can be stored in a 32-bit int is 2147483647.

Use `long long`.